# S3 Default Lifecycle Expiration

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

Does S3 have a default lifecycle for expiration? IOW, does a key automatically expire after x days? Or does it exist forever?

Thanks

Comment: By default, an object on S3 doesn't has a expiration date. If you don't specify a lifestyle rule, it will be there forever.

Comment: thanks, make it a response, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, an object on S3 doesn't has a expiration date. If you don't specify a lifecycle rule, it will be there forever.

You can upload a file to the bucket without the lifecycle rule, check the properties of object, the Expiry Date is none